# use cases for 2 enterprise (ear files) with the same runtime name in it's container?

Tags: deployment, jboss, war, ear, wildfly

I was perusing the Wildfly native management api and came across this description of the runtime-name property of a deployment operation:

> [**runtime-name**] "Name by which the deployment should be known within a server's runtime. This would be equivalent to the file name of a deployment file, and would form the basis for such things as default Java Enterprise Edition application and module names. This would typically be the same as 'name', but in some cases users may wish to have two deployments with the same 'runtime-name' (e.g. two versions of \"foo.war\") both available in the deployment content repository, in which case the deployments would need to have distinct 'name' values but would have the same 'runtime-name'.",

Does this mean that it is possible to run two deployments with the same runtime name or could i only start one of them up at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you can upload as many as you want, but only one can be enabled at any given time.
It can be useful when you are uploading new version of application and you can just switch version (stop old one, and start new one) afterwards or maybe even in middle of the night if that suits your needs.